# How to remove multiple items from a list, not just access them

Tags: python, list

```
removed_card = random.sample(deck, 5)
```

This is allowing me to access the values in the list, but it will leave them in the list. How do I make it where I can remove multiple items from the list at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isnt the best way, but you can instead pick 5 indices inside of your list and pop those indices:

```
removed_cards = []
    for _ in range(5):
        removed_cards.append(deck.pop(randint(len(deck))))
```

`list.pop(i)` removes the item at index `i`. You can't do a list comprehension this way since `deck.pop` will be changing the length of `deck` which would cause index errors.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `remove()` function and remove it from the list like so:

```
import random

cards = random.sample(deck, 5)
cards.remove(deck)
```

I can't be sure if it works because I don't know what 'deck' is.

Comment: `cards.remove(deck)` would not work. that is attempting to remove the original list from the sample that you get from `random.sample`.